# Spark job does not create new dir in s3 bucket on write

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I need to save the data using Spark to AWS S3 bucket that is not owned by me. Each time I try to write to the existing directory the data is not saved. When I change the path to save to new directory this directory is not created and I get `sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist error` on the run.

Here's how I write to s3 bucket using Spark:

```
df
.repartition(1)
.write
.format("parquet")
.option("maxRecordsPerFile", "1000000")
.option("headers", "false")
.option("compression", "gzip")
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.save(path)
```

And that's s3 configuration in my job setup:

```
 spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
 spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key: ${key.qa}
 spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key: ${secret.qa}
```

Should there be some additional setup to write to s3 bucket using Spark job?

Comment: Is your `path` of the form `s3a://bucket_name/prefix`?

Comment: And you are missing the output format. It should something like `df.write.parquet...` or `df.write.format("parquet")...`

Comment: @Gabip Yes, the path is of that format. I've missed the format in the question but not in the actual code.